# Index of abelian groups equals the index of the core and the image

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

I am supposed to proof the following theorem:

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $B\leq A$. In addition let $f: A \to A'$ be an homomorphism of two abelian groups. Show that:
$[A:B] = [\text{im}(A) : \text{im}(B)][\text{ker}(A):\text{ker}(b)]$

So using the theorem of Lagrance and an isomorphism from $\frac{G}{\text{ker}(f)} \to \text{im}(f)$ I've already proofen the theorem for finite groups. However we only introduced the theorem of Lagrance for finite groups and I didn't even use the fact that $A,B$ are abelian groups so I assume I am missing something. I really would appreciate some help ^^

Edit: I just had a look into our script and we also wrote the last line with this notation: [A:B] = [$A^f$:$B^f$] : [$A_f$:$B_f$] is this a more wide spread notation?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{ker}(b)$ supposed to mean?  Homomorphisms have kernels, not subgroups.

Comment: @Randall I've seen that notation refer to the kernel of the morphism restricted to a subgroup.

Comment: So is that not just $\mathrm{ker}(f) \cap B$ in this case?

Comment: @Randall $B$ is not a subgroup of $A'$.

Comment: Yes Don Thousand is right. It means the ker(f) with f: B -> B' while B' is a subset of A'. And for ker(A) it's just ker(f) with the whole homomorphism.

Comment: Is $B'$ supposed to be the image of $f|_B$, or any old suitable codomain so that the map still makes sense?

Comment: @Randall Yes! Sry my mathematical english isn't that great yet so I am struggling a little :(

Comment: No problem, just trying to understand the question.

Comment: Seems like syntax is the problem here after all …

Comment: ok you got me on this one :o

Comment: @k.stm I added a different notation I found in our script. Is this the more commonly used one?